# executable jar file not running

Tags: java, jar, executable

I have created a runnable Jar file of quite large dimension (125,000 kb). When I run it the application inside this jar file is not shown but in the Task Manager the javaw.exe (which should be linked to this jar file) process is running. Does anyone know what the problem is and how it may be overcome?

Comment: Can you post some code that has the minimal amount to reproduce the error. Are you showing your JFrame ?

Answer (score 4):

From the command line, run your application using java.exe -jar jarname.jar (not javaw.exe), so you'll see the errors and exceptions printed to the system out or system err if there is any.

Comment: I did it. There is no error: after entering the code and pressing the Enter button the hyphen keeps flashing, meaning that the application is running, but nothing is displayed

Comment: So this can mean that application does something... What do you expect from it to do?

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass some code in the main class
example : if you want to open a form then write in main class the following command:-
           new ().setVisible(true);